# Importing modules from other projects in Android Studio (1.0.2)

Tags: android, ubuntu, module, android-studio

I am trying to import modules from another android studio project to my project, I get module already exists, my gradle.setting looks like this

```
include ':openCVLibrary249'
include ':imageQ'
```

the "other" project has an app module and a gestureImage module, none of which match my existing modules. I once had a unsuccessful import, but I cleared everything I knew.

I rebuild the project, restarted android studio, cleared my gradle.setting. None of them helped.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Any helps instead of clueless vote downs is really appreciated!

Comment: I am also have the same issues can not find any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the issues by simply  copy paste the module  to project folder . then i edit the settings.gradle  file its works for me.

Comment: Thanks, actually it made me go to the folder and find out, that my previous unsuccessful import, had copied the modules there. Now the import module works fine for me.